# firebase experimental:functions:shell not reloading updated code

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cli

I am following this post @ https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/streamline-typescript-development-cloud-functions.html

I setup a Typescript project for Cloud functions. I have my code in `src/index.ts`, the transpiled code @ `lib/index.js`.

- I start the shell with the command `firebase experimental:functions:shell --debug`
- and have `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch` in other terminal

The TS to JS compilation is happening. But the shell is not picking up the updated code as explained in the above article. I am to quit the shell (Ctrl+C * 3) and then run it again to get the latest code.

My Firebase tools version: 3.17.4

**Update 1:**

Am running in Ubuntu Linux 17.04. The logs shows no errors. But I am getting my console logs, as follows:

> firebase > newPledgeListener({foo: "bar"})
>
> 'Successfully invoked function.'
>
> firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
>
> info: BYE 6
>
> info: Transaction success,  undefined
>
> info: Execution took 2852 ms, user function completed successfully

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you on?  Anything in the output of the CLI?  Run it with --debug for more details?

Comment: Updating the details in Question.

Comment: Did you try running with the --debug flag on the command line?

Comment: Yes. But no new logs that helped

Comment: As the author of that blog, I can say it definitely worked for me.  I use Macos.  Do you get reloads with a JavaScript oriented project?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** A workaround is to install Watchman from source (or linuxbrew).

---

**Original Answer**

I have been having the same issue on Linux. I could get the hellow world example in JavaScript to hot reload but not the TypeScript example. It seems that firebase serve only watches the index.js in the directory it is running from (if not configured in `firebase.json` would be in the `functions/` directory).

To get my project reloading for TypeScript (and I assume more complex JavaScript layouts) I had to use Webpack to output a single file `functions/dist/index.js` and configure Firebase to look for my functions code in `functions/dist`. This then makes hot reload work for both `firebase functions:shell` and `firebase serve`.

My current workflow is to run `webpack --watch` in one terminal with `firebase serve --only functions` in another.

**Updated firebase.json**

```
{    
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build",
    "source": "functions/dist"
  }
}
```

One issue with this approach is that `firebase deploy` fails with the source entry as it expects a package.json in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if my functions depended on files that ended in something other than just `.ts` the function shell would stop "watching" updates. I believe this is the case for the emulator too. The `tsc --watch` command was working - the generated javascript files were updating - but the function shell wasn't picking up the update. Renaming the files restored "watching" functionality. In other words, don't make your function depend on files name `foo.logic.ts` or `bar.service.ts`. Instead name those files `foo.ts` and `bar.ts`.